# Rails is not routing to my Twilio controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I have a paid account with Twilio. In my rails app I have a very simple setup to answer an incoming phone call in rails with twilio. In `routes.rb`, I have

```
post 'communications/answer_phone' => 'communications#answer_phone'
```

In `communications_controller.rb`, I have

```
class CommunicationsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  def answer_phone
    logger.debug '******** answered'
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say "Yay! You’re on Rails!", voice: "alice"
    end
    render :xml => response.to_xml
  end
end
```

If I try to call my Twilio number, ngrok says `500 Internal Server Error`, so I know the request is getting to ngrok. If I look at my rails log file, I see

```
Started POST "/communications/answer_phone" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2017-02-02 21:47:06 +1100
```

so, the request is making it to my application. I don't get `******** answered` in my log file from `logger.debug`. The request never makes it to my `answer_phone` action. Any ideas what could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've done `rake routes` and that gives me

```
communications_receive_sms POST /communications/answer_phone(.:format) communications#answer_phone
```

That looks correct. If I deliberately spell the route incorrectly in `routes.rb`, I get this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/communications/answer_phone"):
```

So I know the request is getting to my rails application and I know it is finding the route. What could cause rails to find the appropriate route but fail the call the associated action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a bug in rails 4.18. There is an example on the internet that makes it happen. See the link below

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/calling-rails-5-getting-started-with-twilio-on-rails.html

The example is for rails 5, so the bug must be fixed now. The following code line causes the error.

```
r.Say "Yay! You’re on Rails!", voice: "alice"
```

The apostrophe in `"Yay! You’re on Rails!"` is not the standard one on my computer keyboard. The normal apostrophe is hex character 0x27, the one in the word You’re is hex character 0x92. This causes a parsing error in rails. Even if I route to a different action in that controller, the error still occurs.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

**EDIT**

If you change the apostrophe, you'll have to restart your rails server to correct the problem